# Presenting a NIB Modally Crashes on iOS 8 but not on iOS 9+

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, nib

I have created a NIB which has a name of `SomeViewController` and all the corresponding code are correct and all the views are bound correctly, but somehow the code `self.presentViewController(SomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)` causes a crash:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What is the problem?

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: @AhmadF `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` I've fixed it though with my answer below. It's pretty weird as to why this happens though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this we need to version check by doing this

```
    if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        self.presentViewController(SomeViewController(nibName: "SomeViewController", bundle: nil), animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.presentViewController(SomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

or just

```
self.presentViewController(SomeViewController(nibName: "SomeViewController", bundle: nil), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

for some reason iOS 8's not automated on including the nibName on initialization with it's corresponding class.

Update:

Can also be fixed by doing this

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "SomeViewController'sNibNameHere", bundle: nil)
    }
}

// on some other part of your code
self.presentViewController(SomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You should mark Your answer, because for now this seems as valid solution as any :).

Comment: I had to wait for 2 days to mark my own answer haha