# UIViewController does not load its xib correctly

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am reproducing the following case and am hoping to find out whats the theoretical cause of the problem. The problem is as follows:

When I declare a new Swift view controller and nib pair, sometimes the view controller's outlets don't load at all ( the nib doesn't load at all ). This happens only on specific devices ( in my case on iPad mini 1, non retina, iOS 8.4.1. On all other devices that I have on my disposal everything works as expected.

The solution that I found is to override the init with nib method :

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: Constants.viewControllerNibName, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

When I enter the nib name manually everything works as expected on all devices.

Can someone enlighten me a little, why this is needed and whats the cause of the problem.

The most interesting part of all is that the issue happens only on a very small subset of devices (in my case one, mentioned above).

UPDATE: It seems that the problem happens only on iOS 8 and not on iOS 9+, found that while testing and from the ticket linked below from Zonily Jame.

Comment: is the viewControllerNibName static?

Comment: I completely answered the question before reading it very well. I haven't directly tried to do what you are talking about, but I should have valuable input if you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: LOL we had the same issue [Nib Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860839/presenting-a-nib-modally-crashes-on-ios-8-but-not-on-ios-9) but instead of specific devices, mine just won't start on specific os's

Comment: you could also do this instead of overriding the `init(nibname: bundle:)` method

`required init() {
super.init(nibName: Constants.viewControllerNibName, bundle: nil)
}`

Comment: Thanks for the swift responses :). The issue may be caused by an iOS specific version, my only device with iOS 8 is the mentioned device above, I will do some more testing and let You know of the results.

PS : @ZonilyJame, yes You can add the code a required init method too. :)

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the answer, Instead post it as an answer to your question

Comment: My question is about the underlining cause of this problem, so there is no valid answer yet :).

Comment: In addition to the top comment, it remains to be seen if this approach can be considered as valid answer ( solution ) of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to mannually setup a viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(style: .plain)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Then I just setup the frame and add it as a subview.

```
let vc = ViewController()!
vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: xValue, y: yValue, width: desiredWidth, height: desiredHeight)
view.addSubview(vc.view)
addChildViewController(vc)
vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

and remove it by saying

```
vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
vc.removeFromParentViewController()
vc = nil
```

Comment: OP is wanting to load a viewcontroller with nib. You solution doesn't work for that.